# How do I specify what provisional profile RoboVM Gradle uses?

Tags: gradle, robovm

I searched around a bit and I found to edit build.gradle to be something like this

```
project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "robovm"

    .....

    robovm {
        iosSignIdentity = ""
        iosProvisioningProfile = ""
        iosSkipSigning = false    
    }
 }
```

However, no matter what format I put inside the quotations, I get an error when calling gradlew ios:createIPA that the String is wrong. I tried absolute path of the certificate and profile, the name of it displayed inside Keychain Access, none work.

Is anyone familiar with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

the iosSignIdentity can be found here:

```
$ security find-identity -v -p codesigning
1) ABC123 "iPhone Developer: ME (ABC12345)"
2) DEF456 "iPhone Distribution: ME (ABC34578)"
 2 valid identities found
```

You need to specify the string, for example "*iPhone Distribution: ME (ABC34578)*"

Your provisioning profile is the 'exact' name that appears in XCode (sorry, I don't know the command for this)

Click on *XCode* -> *Preferences* -> *Accounts* -> Select your Apple ID -> *View Details*
If your provisioning profiles aren't there, click the refresh button

So, your configuration block should look something like this:

> robovm {
>
> ```
> iosSignIdentity = 'iPhone Distribution: ME (ABC34578)'
> iosProvisioningProfile = 'PROD PROVISIONING PROFILE'
> ```
>
> }

Comment: The correct place to get the string for the iosProvisioningProfile is in Apple's "Certificates, Identifiers &  Profiles" / Profiles page, and is the value at the first column "name".

Comment: The aforementioned "Certificates Identifiers and Profiles" page can be found on apples developers page https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list