# Intellij RoboVM creating IPA

Tags: ios, intellij-idea, ipa, robovm

I just installed the Intellij RoboVM plug in but there is no option for Build > CreateIPA. I have seen many tutorials where you can create a .ipa from intellij. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MichaelVoznesensky because that's not supported by RoboVM.

Comment: I'm not sure of the "correct" way to do it, but you can check the Gradle tasks available and choose the `createIPA` task.

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered [How do I specify what provisional profile RoboVM Gradle uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175848/how-do-i-specify-what-provisional-profile-robovm-gradle-uses)

Just use `./gradlew createIPA` and be sure to use add signing configuration in the build.gradle in ios directory 

`robovm {
    // Configure robovm
    iosSignIdentity = "YOUR IDENDITY"
    iosProvisioningProfile = "YOUR PROVISIONING PROFILE"
    iosSkipSigning = false
    stdoutFifo = ""
    stderrFifo = ""
}`

as given in https://github.com/robovm/robovm-gradle-plugin